# Native events behaves differently on different versions of firefox with selenium

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Earlier I was using Firefox 25.0.1 and Selenium 2.42.2 to test my web-app. It consists of a menu tab, hovering over which gave sub menus and then I have to click on one of the sub menus. I was using following code:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(getFFWebDriver());
Action action = actions.moveToElement(getFFWebDriver().findElement(By.id("main.menu"))).build();
action.perform();
getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"submenu\"]/span")).click();
```

But when I upgraded my browser to version 28 it doesn't work like , it used to.
I also tried upgrading selenium version to 2.46, still it doesn't work like as it used to with selenium 2.42 and FF-25.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FF 25? That's really old

Comment: That's what on older version it was working great but even i upgrade my browser to 26 the above code break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it works like this:

```
WebElement menu = driver.findElement(men);
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.moveToElement(menu).moveToElement(driver.findElement(submenu)).click().build().perform();
```

This works even i upgrade FF 25 -> 30 and also works well on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Native event support for firefox webdriver tend to be for a few specific versions of the browsers for each release of selenium. I suspect your versions of selenium doesn't support native events in firefox 28.

The changelog for V2.42 doesn't say what version of firefox they support for native events but apparently V28 of firefox was supported in V2.41. You could always try downgrading to that version of selenium or try firefox 33 on selenium V2.46 which looks like the latest version of firefox that has native event support.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG

There is also the option of going for synthetic events over native events.

Comment: I tried with the latest version of FF i.e 33 with selenium v 2.46 Still same issue.

Comment: You didn't upgrade to V39 by mistake did you? That is the latest version of FF but selenium won't support that for native events.

Comment: No i didn't. Actually my sub menus are coming in such a way that due to that it's making it hard when i update FF. but also it works perfectly fine in chrome and FF25.